# if data not exist on a particular date then how to select the date which is previous and very close to given date in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which have the following fields

```
Sno  StockDate   PartNo      Quantity    Location
1    22.11.2013  011011011    100        Perungudi
2    24.12.2013  011201120    1000       Kottivakkam
3    1.1.2014    011011011     80        Perungudi
```

If i need to select datas on 1.1.2014 means  i have to list the following datas

```
Sno  StockDate   PartNo      Quantity    Location

    2    24.12.2013  011201120    1000       Kottivakkam
    3    1.1.2014    011011011     80        Perungudi
```

that is the stock available on that day is as showed above. i want to know how to i write the select query

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808356/how-to-determine-values-for-missing-months-based-on-data-of-previous-months-in-t

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i want to know what is n in firstof month